# React .env files display in console but not in fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I have a react app created with create-react-app, I also have a .env in the root folder with `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL`.

In my localhost environment, everything works as expected but when I build and deploy to Firebase then I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

In the method, if I output it to the console `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL)` then the url is written to the console and I can click it and go to the home page which is just a json response (for testing).

However, in the following code, I get the SyntaxError as above

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/`, {
mode:"cors",
credentials :"include",
method : "GET",
headers : {
   Accept : "application/json",
   "Content-Type"  :"application/json"
   }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
     setHello(data.message)
     console.log(data.message)
})
.catch(er => {
     console.log("fetch was caught")
     console.log(er)
})
```

If I`console.log(process.env)` then I can see the object with the correct value for the server url and if i replace the url in the fetch from the .env variable to hardcoded url (exact same as what gets printed to the console eg `https://serverapi.com/`) then everything works as expected again, and I see the data.message.

I've tried something like `const {REACT_APP_SERVER_URL} = process.env` but that didn't work either.

I'm running out of ideas as to why I get the error with the environment variable.

Comment: Be careful about trusting `then(response => response.json())` blindly. [Fetch will **not** throw an error if you get back an unexpected error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) like 404, 500, etc. You should make sure to check `response.ok` and handle it appropriately first. Without it, you might end up calling `setHello(undefined)` which could cause issues. You should also be wary of zero-length responses (204, 304, empty text files) which will throw messages like "Unexpected end of JSON input".

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look at adding something in to handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clicked as I was typing this but in my .env file I had
`REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=https://server.com/`
then in the fetch I had
`` fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/`) ``
So because I had a `/` at the end of the SERVER_URL line and also in the fetch call then the final code had two `//` and looked like `https://server.com//` which was the issue. I fixed this by removing the `/` in the .env file